# Dir not returning latest files in a for loop

Tags: batch-file

I have a rather interesting delima. I'm trying to find the latest 7 files in a directory. If I just run `dir /o-d /a-d /b|find /n /v ""` from a command prompt, it returns the latest 7 files at the top but if I run it inside of a for loop in a batch file, it doesn't. They are out of order. The code I'm using is:

```
@echo off
setlocal

cd /d %~dp0

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /o-n /b /a-d^|find /n /v ""' ) do (
    echo %%a
)
```

I'm planning to use the numbers with a `for /l` loop to get the newest 7 files but I can't until I figure out why this is happening. Here are the files that show the difference.

```
F:\Scripts\Batch\Test\Check7>dir /o-d /a-d |find /n /v ""
[1] Volume in drive F is home
[2] Volume Serial Number is 0101-23B6
[3]
[4] Directory of F:\Scripts\Batch\Test\Check7
[5]
[6]08/26/2016  09:58 AM               256 Check7.cmd
[7]08/25/2016  05:48 PM               544 RexxTable.txt
[8]08/25/2016  05:48 PM           115,668 FCSBalanceFile.txt
[9]08/25/2016  05:48 PM            33,051 FCSFlatFile.txt
[10]08/25/2016  05:48 PM         1,475,304 ITF_MT_Deloitte_CRR.txt
[11]08/25/2016  05:48 PM                92 ITF_LOB_Strike.txt
[12]08/25/2016  05:48 PM           387,673 ITF_LOB_Daily.txt
[13]08/25/2016  05:48 PM            20,944 DDAFlatFile.txt
[14]08/24/2016  05:46 PM           115,668 FCSBalanceFile-08252016.txt
[15]08/24/2016  05:46 PM            22,894 FCSFlatFile-08252016.txt
[16]08/24/2016  05:46 PM            19,448 DDAFlatFile-08252016.txt
[17]08/23/2016  05:49 PM           115,668 FCSBalanceFile-08242016.txt
[18]08/23/2016  05:49 PM            31,730 FCSFlatFile-08242016.txt
[19]08/23/2016  05:48 PM            22,440 DDAFlatFile-08242016.txt
[20]08/22/2016  05:50 PM           115,560 FCSBalanceFile-08232016.txt
[21]08/22/2016  05:50 PM            38,748 FCSFlatFile-08232016.txt
[22]08/22/2016  05:49 PM            31,042 DDAFlatFile-08232016.txt
[23]08/19/2016  05:48 PM           115,560 FCSBalanceFile-08222016.txt
[24]08/19/2016  05:48 PM            22,242 FCSFlatFile-08222016.txt
[25]08/19/2016  05:48 PM            18,326 DDAFlatFile-08222016.txt
[26]08/18/2016  05:49 PM           115,560 FCSBalanceFile-08192016.txt
[27]08/18/2016  05:49 PM            34,588 FCSFlatFile-08192016.txt
[28]08/18/2016  05:48 PM            20,196 DDAFlatFile-08192016.txt
[29]08/17/2016  05:49 PM           115,560 FCSBalanceFile-08182016.txt
[30]08/17/2016  05:49 PM            22,507 FCSFlatFile-08182016.txt
[31]08/17/2016  05:49 PM            19,448 DDAFlatFile-08182016.txt
[32]08/16/2016  05:49 PM           115,452 FCSBalanceFile-08172016.txt
[33]08/16/2016  05:49 PM            30,712 FCSFlatFile-08172016.txt
[34]08/16/2016  05:49 PM            26,180 DDAFlatFile-08172016.txt

F:\Scripts\Batch\Test\Check7>Check7.cmd
[1] Volume in drive F is home
[2] Volume Serial Number is 0101-23B6
[3]
[4] Directory of F:\Scripts\Batch\Test\Check7
[5]
[6]08/25/2016  05:48 PM               544 RexxTable.txt
[7]08/25/2016  05:48 PM         1,475,304 ITF_MT_Deloitte_CRR.txt
[8]08/25/2016  05:48 PM                92 ITF_LOB_Strike.txt
[9]08/25/2016  05:48 PM           387,673 ITF_LOB_Daily.txt
[10]08/24/2016  05:46 PM            22,894 FCSFlatFile-08252016.txt
[11]08/23/2016  05:49 PM            31,730 FCSFlatFile-08242016.txt
[12]08/22/2016  05:50 PM            38,748 FCSFlatFile-08232016.txt
[13]08/19/2016  05:48 PM            22,242 FCSFlatFile-08222016.txt
[14]08/18/2016  05:49 PM            34,588 FCSFlatFile-08192016.txt
[15]08/17/2016  05:49 PM            22,507 FCSFlatFile-08182016.txt
[16]08/16/2016  05:49 PM            30,712 FCSFlatFile-08172016.txt
[17]08/25/2016  05:48 PM            33,051 FCSFlatFile.txt
[18]08/24/2016  05:46 PM           115,668 FCSBalanceFile-08252016.txt
[19]08/23/2016  05:49 PM           115,668 FCSBalanceFile-08242016.txt
[20]08/22/2016  05:50 PM           115,560 FCSBalanceFile-08232016.txt
[21]08/19/2016  05:48 PM           115,560 FCSBalanceFile-08222016.txt
[22]08/18/2016  05:49 PM           115,560 FCSBalanceFile-08192016.txt
[23]08/17/2016  05:49 PM           115,560 FCSBalanceFile-08182016.txt
[24]08/16/2016  05:49 PM           115,452 FCSBalanceFile-08172016.txt
[25]08/25/2016  05:48 PM           115,668 FCSBalanceFile.txt
[26]08/24/2016  05:46 PM            19,448 DDAFlatFile-08252016.txt
[27]08/23/2016  05:48 PM            22,440 DDAFlatFile-08242016.txt
[28]08/22/2016  05:49 PM            31,042 DDAFlatFile-08232016.txt
[29]08/19/2016  05:48 PM            18,326 DDAFlatFile-08222016.txt
[30]08/18/2016  05:48 PM            20,196 DDAFlatFile-08192016.txt
[31]08/17/2016  05:49 PM            19,448 DDAFlatFile-08182016.txt
[32]08/16/2016  05:49 PM            26,180 DDAFlatFile-08172016.txt
[33]08/25/2016  05:48 PM            20,944 DDAFlatFile.txt
[34]08/26/2016  09:58 AM               256 Check7.cmd
```

Comment: Your batch file sorts by name: `/o-n` whereas the manually typed command does it by date.

Comment: @WoxxOm Lol. Duh. That was an id10t error. Thanks for pointing it out. Post it as an answer and I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: Since the issue is a simple typo, the question is not worth to be answered as it does not add any value to this site; rather it should be closed (that is what I voted for)... refer to this help topic about what questions are on-topic: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You are also using the /B option in the batch file but not at the command line.

Comment: The command line was really just a test. I'm not sure how I switched the `/o-n` because I copied it right from my batch file but obviously I did. I'm going to post the finished batch and answer my own question with it. thanks for all the useful comments everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the finished batch file.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%a in (
    'dir /o-d /a-d /b^|find /n /v ""' ) do (
    echo %%~nxtb>>%~n0.txt
    if %%a geq 7 goto :out
)
:out
```